# Reverse dump of a compact string into variable in Perl

Tags: perl, parsing, dump

I have a structure given like this:

```
my %Tr106IPInterfaceXsListSyntax = (
      tr69InstanceId22079 => {type => 'INTEGER', Ordinal => 0},
      tr106IPv4AddressXsBifoldList_001 => {
        type => [
          { Tr106IPv4AddressXsBifoldListSyntax => {
            tr69InstanceId22082 => {type => 'INTEGER', Ordinal => 0},
            iPAddress21929 => {type => 'STRING', Ordinal => 1},
            subnetMask21930 => {type => 'STRING', Ordinal => 2},
            addressingType22310 => {type => 'ENUMERATION', Ordinal => 3}
            }
          }
        ],
        Ordinal => 1
      },       
      tr106IPv6AddressXsBifoldList_001 => {
         type => [
          { Tr106IPv6AddressXsBifoldListSyntax => {
            tr69InstanceId22330 => {type => 'INTEGER', Ordinal => 0},
            iPAddress22326 => {type => 'STRING', Ordinal => 1},
            origin22327 => {type => 'ENUMERATION', Ordinal => 2}
            }
          }
        ],
        Ordinal => 2
      },
      iPv4Enable22321 => {type => 'BOOLEAN', Ordinal => 3},
      status21926 => {type => 'ENUMERATION', Ordinal => 4},
      name22274 => {type => 'STRING', Ordinal => 5},
      lastChange21927 => {type => 'INTEGER', Ordinal => 6},
      lowerLayers22080 => {type => [ 'STRING' ], Ordinal => 7},
      type22309 => {type => 'ENUMERATION', Ordinal => 8},
      iPv4AddressNumberOfEntries21928 => {type => 'INTEGER', Ordinal => 9},
      iPv6AddressNumberOfEntries22322 => {type => 'INTEGER', Ordinal => 10},
      iPv6Enable22323 => {type => 'BOOLEAN', Ordinal => 11}
    );
```

From an external source I get a string like this:

```
"[{1,[{1,'10.16.195.16','255.255.254.0',DHCP}],[],true,UP,'',0,[''],NORMAL,1,0,false},{2,[{1,'10.15.128.69','255.255.255.255',IKEV2}],[],false,UP,'4g_core_tunnel',1,[''],TUNNEL,1,0,false}]"
```

or the same string pretty-printed

```
"[
  { 1, 
    [ {1, '10.16.195.16', '255.255.254.0', DHCP} ],
    [ ],
    true,
    UP,
    '',
    0,
    [''],
    NORMAL,
    1,
    0,
    false
  },
  { 2,
    [ {1, '10.15.128.69', '255.255.255.255', IKEV2 } ],
    [],
    false,
    UP,
    '4g_core_tunnel',
    1,
    [''],
    TUNNEL,
    1,
    0,
    false
   }
]"
```

How to convert this compact string into a usable variable like this one:

```
my $var = [
   {
      tr69InstanceId22079 => 1,
      tr106IPv4AddressXsBifoldList_001 => [
         { 
            tr69InstanceId22082 => 1,
            iPAddress21929 => '10.16.195.16',
            subnetMask21930 => '255.255.254.0',
            addressingType22310 => "DHCP"
         }
      ],       
      tr106IPv6AddressXsBifoldList_001 => [],
      iPv4Enable22321 => "true",
      status21926 => "UP",
      name22274 => '',
      lastChange21927 => 0,
      lowerLayers22080 => [ '' ],
      type22309 => "NORMAL",
      iPv4AddressNumberOfEntries21928 => 1,
      iPv6AddressNumberOfEntries22322 => 0,
      iPv6Enable22323 => "false"
   },
   {
      tr69InstanceId22079 => 2,
      tr106IPv4AddressXsBifoldList_001 => [
         { 
            tr69InstanceId22082 => 1,
            iPAddress21929 => '10.15.128.69',
            subnetMask21930 => '255.255.255.255',
            addressingType22310 => "IKEV2"
         }
      ],       
      tr106IPv6AddressXsBifoldList_001 => [],
      iPv4Enable22321 => "false",
      status21926 => "UP",
      name22274 => '4g_core_tunnel',
      lastChange21927 => 1,
      lowerLayers22080 => [ '' ],
      type22309 => "TUNNEL",
      iPv4AddressNumberOfEntries21928 => 1,
      iPv6AddressNumberOfEntries22322 => 0,
      iPv6Enable22323 => "false"
   }   
]
```

In my script I have around 30 different structures, so preferably it should be generic (i.e. dynamic and most likely recursive) solution. I guess I have to compose a regular expression and then process the groups one by one. Maybe there is a module which can do this and I don't have to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: `@var = [ ... ]` should almost always be `$var = [ ... ]` since you're assigning a single scalar value (an array reference) to a variable.

Comment: @Shawn that's a detail, I can tune it, if needed. Challenge is to parse the input string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question I asked is a bit different than my actual duty, however I wanted to limit the scope of my question. In the end I have to insert all this data into a relational Oracle database, thus it is not really required to have the full structure in a variable.

Main goal was to derive everything only from given structure. From the structure I am able to compose regular expressions. In this example it would be

- `\{(\d+),\[.*?],\[.*?],(true|false),(\w+),('.*?'),(\d+),(\[.*?]),(\w+),(\d+),(\d+),(true|false)}`
- `\{(\d+),('.*?'),('.*?'),(\w+)}`
- `\{(\d+),('.*?'),(\w+)}`

Then I execute these regular expressions and use the matches.

```
use Data::Dumper;
    
my @result;
my $input = "[{1,[{1,'10.16.195.16','255.255.254.0',DHCP}],[],true,UP,'',0,[''],NORMAL,1,0,false},{2,[{1,'10.15.128.69','255.255.255.255',IKEV2}],[],false,UP,'4g_core_tunnel',1,[''],TUNNEL,1,0,false}]";

my @regex;
my @attr = sort { $Tr106IPInterfaceXsListSyntax{$a}{Ordinal} <=> $Tr106IPInterfaceXsListSyntax{$b}{Ordinal} } keys %Tr106IPInterfaceXsListSyntax;
foreach my $key ( @attr ) {
  if ( $Tr106IPInterfaceXsListSyntax{$key}{type} eq 'STRING' )   {
    push(@regex, "('.*?')");    
  } elsif ( $Tr106IPInterfaceXsListSyntax{$key}{type} eq 'BOOLEAN' )   {
    push(@regex, "(true|false)");
  } elsif ( $Tr106IPInterfaceXsListSyntax{$key}{type} eq 'INTEGER' )   {
    push(@regex, "(\\d+)");
  } elsif ( $Tr106IPInterfaceXsListSyntax{$key}{type} eq 'ENUMERATION' )   {
    push(@regex, "(\\w+)");
  } elsif ( ref($Tr106IPInterfaceXsListSyntax{$key}{type}) eq 'ARRAY' && $Tr106IPInterfaceXsListSyntax{$key}{type}[0] eq 'STRING' )   {
    push(@regex, "(\\[.*?])");
  } else {
    push(@regex, "\\[.*?]");
  }
}
my $regex = '\\{' . join(',', @regex) . '}';

while ( $input =~ m/$regex/g ) {
  my %Tr106IPInterface = {};
  foreach $pos (1..$#-) {
    $Tr106IPInterface{$attr[$pos-1]} = substr( $input, $-[$pos], $+[$pos] - $-[$pos]);
  }
  push(@result, \%Tr106IPInterface); 
  # ... do some more stuff with %Tr106IPInterface
}

print Dumper \@result;
```

The nested structure are not covered yet in this code, however it shows the principle I will follow.

Answer (score 1):

This is a two phase problem. First you have to convert the string into a viable perl structure.

Assuming that you have control of the data you recieve, you can use eval for that.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $data_as_string = "[{1,[{1,'10.16.195.16','255.255.254.0',DHCP}],[],true,UP,'',0,[''],NORMAL,1,0,false},{2,[{1,'10.15.128.69','255.255.255.255',IKEV2}],[],false,UP,'4g_core_tunnel',1,[''],TUNNEL,1,0,false}]";

# Change {} into [] as we dont have the attributes ye
$data_as_string =~ s/\{/[/g;
$data_as_string =~ s/\}/]/g;

# Quote String constants.
$data_as_string =~ s/(?<=[,\[])(\w*[a-z]\w*)(?=[,\]])/'$1'/ig;

my $data = eval $data_as_string;
```

then you have to iterate over the result and generate your objects. Easiest way, is to write a function for each type.

```
my @result;
foreach my $ele (@$data) {
    push @result, get_Tr106IPInterfaceXs( $ele);
}

sub get_Tr106IPInterfaceXs {
    my $array = shift;
    return 
    {
      tr69InstanceId22079 => $array->[0],
      tr106IPv4AddressXsBifoldList_001 => [
        map {get_tr106IPv4AddressXsBifold($_)} @{$array->[1]}
      ],       
      tr106IPv6AddressXsBifoldList_001 => $array->[2],
      iPv4Enable22321 => $array->[3],
      status21926 => $array->[4],
      name22274 => $array->[5],
      lastChange21927 => $array->[6],
      lowerLayers22080 => $array->[7],
      type22309 => $array->[8],
      iPv4AddressNumberOfEntries21928 => $array->[9],
      iPv6AddressNumberOfEntries22322 => $array->[10],
      iPv6Enable22323 => $array->[11]
    }
}

sub get_tr106IPv4AddressXsBifold {
    my $array = shift;
    return  { 
            tr69InstanceId22082 => $array->[0],
            iPAddress21929 => $array->[1],
            subnetMask21930 => $array->[2],
            addressingType22310 => $array->[3]
    }
}
```

Adding

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@result;
```

at the end, prints everything out as expected.

Comment: I am way too lazy to write 30+ functions. The input data is provided by external system which get new releases usually 1-2 times per year, typically by each release more attributes are added. Everything should be derived from the structure, once the code is done, I will hardly touch it again instead of reviewing it 1-2 times every year. See my answer to get my approach.

Comment: Depending on your "source" this might be the right solution. Anyway you could also think about generating a grammar for some Compiler-Compiler like Parse::RecDecent. https://www.perl.com/pub/2001/06/13/recdecent.html/ or Parse::Yapp https://github.com/wbraswell/parse-yapp